# Channel Capacity - is this only for discrete/digital signals?

Tags: discrete-signals, information-theory

The units of channel capacity is **bits/second**. Does this mean this only refers to discrete/digital signals? Is channel capacity analogous to bandwidth in case of an analog signal transmission?

Comment: I am confused. I do understand the link between channel capacity and mutual information, but to not forget that channel capacity, as in the Shannon coding theorem, is a rate of information, expressed in bits/s, while mutual information is expressed in bits. So how can you equate an information rate with an amount of information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of channel capacity can be applied to either digital or analog cases. The meaning depends on how you calculate it. The definition is:

$$C=\max_{p_X(x)}\ I(X;Y)$$

In the digital world, $p_X(x)$ is a mass probability function and the mutual information is calculated as $H(Y)-H(Y|X)$, where $H(\cdot)$ denotes the entropy.

In the analog case, then $p_X(x)$ is a probability density function and the mutual information is calculated as $h(Y)-h(Y|X)$, where $h(\cdot)$ denotes the [differential entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_entropy).

Regarding your other question, channel capacity and bandwidth are *not* the same thing. Take for example a Gaussian channel, where $$C=B\log_2(1+\mathrm{SNR})$$

You can see that the capacity depends on the bandwidth, but they are clearly not the same.

Comment: To add to this good answer: capacity applies only to digital communication signals; in other words, there is no equivalent for analog AM or FM signals. Having said that, in digital communications you can have a model where the received signal is continuous (for example the AWGN channel) or one where it's discrete (for example the binary symmetric channel), and in each case you get a different expression for the capacity.

Comment: @MBaz There's some entropy in my assessment of your statement: Capacity is the maximum expected mutual information given a channel, $C= \max\limits_{p(x)}I(X;Y)$right? Why would that not apply to the differential entropy case, where $I(X;Y) = D(\,f(x,y)||f(x)f(y)\,)$, thus $$\begin{align}C_{diff.} &= \max\limits_{f(x)} D(\,f(x,y)||f(x)f(y)\,)\\&=\max\limits_{f(x)} \int{f(x)\log\frac fg}(x)\,dx\text,\end{align}$$if I'm not mistaken? Esp. the same $I(X;Y) = h(X) - h(X|Y)$ mutual info/conditional entropy relationship applies,so given the entropy of a noisy reception $h(X|Y)$,I'd see a "capacity".

Comment: @MarcusMüller If I understand well, as soon as you are able to provide a finite value of entropy $h(.)$, this can be considered digital signal. In FM/AM analog message, this measurable information is infinity. And MBaz did not say that the capacity notion can not be applied to differential entropy case (he did mention AWGN channel where this notion is used).

Comment: @AlexTP hm, I'd define diff entropy $h(X) := -\int f(x)\log f(x)\,dx$, and that would be finite for a lot of non-discrete signals, for example, the common result is that the entropy-maximizing finite support density $f$ is the gaussian, with $h(X\sim\mathcal N(\cdot;\sigma^2))= \frac12\log_2 2\pi e\sigma^2$, which is pretty finite, but doesn't enable me to consider the signal digital?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I mean that the signal is $A \neq X$ and $A$ is modulated/mapped to $X$ that can be discrete or continuos. If $A$ is discrete, it is digital message. Differential entropy is not measure of uncertainty but mutual information is still measure of *discrete* information. Let's wait MBaz explain what he wanted to say.

Comment: Obviously the random variable in question can be continuous, as it is in the AWGN channel. What I'm saying is that it doesn't make sense to speak of the "information content" of an AM or FM (or other analog) signal. In the AWGN case the channel input is discrete. Even if the math could be made to work for the case where the channel input is continuous (as I think Marcus is trying to do), I don't think the results can be interpreted in the same sense as in the digital communications case (which is what I think Alex is saying). However, I'd love to see a way to make it work, though!

Comment: @MBaz nicely said! I really have to think about this. I'd argue that differential and discrete entropy both mean "expected information", so I'm still not sure you're right that in the context of continuous sources or analog modulated signals, the idea of a channel capacity wouldn't make sense, as it feels very "intuable" to think of a channel as something that reduces the amount of clarity I get (==entropy!) about the observed signal. You're right, Shannon Information is probably not the appropriate measure.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I've been thinking about it myself... One observation. Consider these two cases: (a) you transmit (on purpose) a noisy AM signal over a noiseless channel; (b) you transmit a clean signal over a noisy channel. There's no way for the receiver to tell the difference.

Comment: That's absolutely true; but think about this: Let $X$ be source, $Y$ be sink; your (b) channel has $I(X;Y) =h(X)-h(X|Y)$. Since noiseless, $h(X|Y)$, the "uncertainty regarding $X$ when $Y$ is known" is simply $0$, thus $I(X;Y)=h(X)$, and with $C=\max\limits_{f(x)}I(X;Y)=\max\limits_{f(x)}h(X)=h_\mathcal{N}$ we get the diff entropy of the Gaussian source I quoted above as the differential channel capacity (the normal distr maximizes diff entropy). Your (a) case has $C=\max\limits_{f(x)}I(X;Y)=\max\limits_{f(x)}h(X)-h(X|Y)$, and because we use the same noise, we set $h(X|Y)=h_\mathcal{N}$.…

Comment: … that yields $C=\max\limits_{f(x)}h(X)-h_\mathcal{N}$, which happens to be exactly what you expect: the entropy of the source minus the entropy of the noise. The argument "can't tell artificial noise from natural noise in terms of entropy" thus holds, but it doesn't mean that describing the entropy in the channel doesn't give us exactly the same as it does for the discrete case – an upper limit for how much info we can push through!

Comment: @Tendero: I am still having trouble understanding the significance of channel capacity if we are dealing it in the analog case. What does, for example, a channel capacity of 100bits/s indicate for an analog signal passing in a channel of bandwidth B?

Comment: @Eliza There is a difference between discrete/analog data and discrete/analog signals. Both analog and digital information can be encoded as either analog or digital signals. Capacity as defined in my answer only applies to digital signals, but that can correspond to either discrete or analog information (the two different cases explained in the answer). If you can access to a copy of Stallings' Data and Computer Communications, check out the chapter "Signal Encoding Techniques".

Comment: @Tendero: Just one thing: so channel capacity cannot be defined like this ($C$) if an analog signal is being transmitted through the medium?

Comment: @Eliza Not as far as I know, as MBaz has stated in the first comment on this thread.

Answer (score 0):

In the audio world, we have this notion of the [Gerzon-Craven limit](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/242019195_Optimal_Noise_Shaping_and_Dither_of_Digital_Signals) of bit reduction in **quantization** (this is not the same as lossy coding in a codec like MP3).  And it just says that the Shannon result goes both ways (digital info over an analog channel and analog signal over a bit-limited digital channel).  And they generalized the Shannon Channel Capacity equation:

$$ C = B \log_2 \left(1+\tfrac{S}{N} \right) $$

to this integral:

$$ C = \int\limits_{0}^{B} \log_2 \left(1+\frac{S(f)}{N(f)} \right) \, \mathrm{d}f $$

$B$ is bandwidth in Hz, $S(f)$ is the power spectrum of the signal, $N(f)$ is the power spectrum of the channel noise (which is, in the reverse direction, the noise from quantization error), $C$ is channel capacity in bits/sec.

So, if you had CD quality audio, that had 96 dB S/N over all of the 22.05 kHz bandwidth, the information needed to represent that 96 dB, 22 kHz audio comes out to be 44100 sample/sec × 16 bits/sample = 705600 bit/sec .

but if you don't need 96 dB S/N over the entire range of human hearing (because of the [Fletcher-Munson curve](https://www.kmuw.org/post/loudness-and-fletcher-munson-curve) at 0 dB), then you don't need as many bits if you can steer the noise from the quantization error from where your hearing is most sensitive to where it is less sensitive.  I dunno what the bit rate comes out to be, but someone can use the integral above (and an expression of the 0 dB curve for $N(f)$) to figure out a smaller bit rate.  Of course, good codecs take advantage of other perceptual masking properties of our hearing to reduce the bit rate much further.  (I am currently contract working for a company that has a 85000 bit/sec high-quality stereo codec.)